# Не отображается страница с плагином bootstrap vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

Установил vue, создал проект, запустил. Тестовый текст отобразился, устанавливаю bootstrap vue по мануалу на https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs. Установил bootstrap vue. Подключаю

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

и в main.js

```
 import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'
```

После чего открываю страницу в локал хосте и она пустая. В чём дело?

Comment: А компоненты в шаблон корневого vue-элемента добавлены? :) Ведь если шаблон пуст, он естественно ничего не будет рендерить. И кстати, BS-vue весьма отсталая штука, которая не поддерживает актуальную третью версию Vue - надо ставить последнюю 2.* (npm i не vue, а vue@2).

Comment: Ой, то есть не vue@next, а vue@2 - я постоянно забываю что мастер-версия пакета еще буксует во второй (указывать @2 все равно желательно... т.к. они в любой момент могут выполнить обещание данное год назад, отрелизив в npm 3.* - и тогда привычка не указывать версию может сыграть злую шутку).